# WebView - disable auto wrap lines, enable horizontal scrollbar

Tags: android, webview

It is possible to disable auto wrap lines and enable horizontal scrollbar in WebView component on Android?

Thanks for help.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Divide this in 2 parts:

Disable auto wrap lines:

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

To enable horizontal scrollbar use:

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```